# Cannot change post request to put request

Tags: java, http

I wrote a class for my HTTP-Request.
My proplem is that although in several lines of this code i added:

```
httpConn.setRequestMethod("PUT");
```

My code still performs POST-Request instead of PUT-Request! What do i wrong? Thanks!

```
public MultipartUtility(String requestURL, String charset)
            throws IOException {
        this.charset = charset;

        // creates a unique boundary based on time stamp
        boundary = "===" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "===";

        URL url = new URL(requestURL);
        httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpConn.setUseCaches(false);
        httpConn.setRequestMethod("PUT");
        httpConn.setDoOutput(true); // indicates POST method
        httpConn.setRequestMethod("PUT");
        httpConn.setDoInput(true);

        httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "CodeJava Agent");
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("Test", "Bonjour");
        outputStream = httpConn.getOutputStream();
        writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, charset),
                true);
    }
```

Comment: httpConn.setUseCaches(false); can effect this result. I am not sure PUT can provide this feature

Comment: @Adem you are right! Please write a answer so that i can mark it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`httpConn.setUseCaches(false);` can effect this result. I am not sure `PUT` can provide this feature